# Multiple aliases present in json during jackson deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a "Request" POJO for my Java API service (Java 11). The POJO is created using Jackson deserialization (jackson databind 2.12.3). One of the POJO's fields has an alias (`@JsonAlias`) for backward compatibility in the API. How do I instruct jackson to throw an error if both versions of the field are present in the json (actual field name version & aliased version) ?

Here's a small demo app for the above scenario:

```java
// Sample POJO
@lombok.Data
public class A {
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias("y")
    private int x; // Field names "x" with alias "y"
}

// Executed code
var om = new ObjectMapper().disable(MapperFeature.IGNORE_MERGE_FOR_UNMERGEABLE);
System.out.println(om.readValue("{\"x\": 1}", A.class));
System.out.println(om.readValue("{\"y\": 1}", A.class));
System.out.println(om.readValue("{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 1}", A.class));
System.out.println(om.readValue("{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2}", A.class));
System.out.println(om.readValue("{\"y\": 1, \"x\": 2}", A.class));

// Output
A(x=1)
A(x=1)
A(x=1)
A(x=2)
A(x=2)
```

I need at least the last 2 cases to fail with a Jackson mapping related exception. The 3rd case may/may not fail (probably should fail, since the equals can get complex at times).

I tried checking if Jackson has anything that can be enabled/disabled in it's databind module's `MapperFeature`s but didn't have any luck.

I also tried checking in `JsonParser.Feature` & `DeserializationFeature`, but these deal more with parsing the actual Json input, rather than handling POJO / annotation processing, so I don't expect anything from in there...

Answer (score 1):

This feature currently does not exist in Jackson.

Feature Request: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3184